# Bound Service usando IntentService

Tags: android, thread, android-service

Estou criando um IntentService com Binder, para eu poder me comunicar com esse serviço a partir de uma Activity

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {
    private ChatManager chatManager;
    private final IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();

    public MyService() {
        super("MyService");
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        if(chatManager == null) chatManager = new ChatManager();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(chatManager != null) {
            chatManager.encerraChatManager();
        }
    }

      public class MyBinder extends Binder{
        public ChatManager getService() {
            return chatManager;
        }
    }
}
```

Na minha atividade,  no método onCreate eu chamo

```
bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

E no método onServiceConnected eu recebo o objeto chatManager

```
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder iBinder) {
        chatManager = ((ChatService.ChatBinder)iBinder).getService();
    }
```

Como o meu método chatManager foi instanciado em um Thread de background eu esperava que o mesmo continuasse sendo executado em background, porém não é. Quando eu chamo qualquer método de chatManager ele é executado na thread principal.

O que estou fazendo de errado ou qual conceito eu não entendi do IntentService no android?

---

EDIÇÃO 31/07/2017 Explicação sobre a Classe ChatManager

o ChatManager abre uma conexão com o banco de dados Realm (realm.io). Com uma conexão aberta, eu posso adicionar mensagens ao chat, encerrar o chat, alterar status, etc. Com isso quero não ter que abrir uma conexão com o banco para cada nova alteração no banco, que é muito frequente e consome muitos recursos.

Por outro lado, não posso fazer as gravações no banco direto na Thread principal, pois esta causando lentidão e até travamento do app.

ChatManager

```
    public class ChatManager {
    private Realm db;
    private Chat chat;

    public ChatManager() {
        db = Realm.getDefaultInstance(); // Uma instancia do banco de dados Realm
    }


    /**
     * Vários método que tem essa estrutura
     */
    public void metodoGernerico(Object param) {
        db.executeTransaction(realm -> {
            // altera o banco de dados
        });
    }

    /**
     * Fecha o banco de dados quando sai da activity
     */
    public void encerraChatManager() {
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IBinder não deve ser usado com o IntentService.

O propósito do IntentService é executar apenas uma tarefa.
Ele é destruído logo após o método `onHandleIntent()` terminar.
Acho até estranho que o método `onServiceConnected()` seja chamado.

Como não sei a finalidade do ChatManager pouco mais posso adiantar.

Uma situação possível seria o ChatManager correr cada um dos seus métodos em uma outra *thread* ou, eventualmente, usar IntentService's para os executar.

Outra é criar um [Bound Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) cujos métodos delegam para o ChatManager as operações a executar.
Use o IBinder para obter o Serviço.

Qualquer coisa assim:

```
public class LocalService extends Service {

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private chatManager = new ChatManager();

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LocalService getService() {
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public void meuMetodo() {
      chatManager.meuMetodo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta,

o ChatManager abre uma conexão com o banco de dados Realm (https://realm.io). Com uma conexão aberta, eu posso adicionar mensagens ao chat, encerrar o chat, alterar status, etc.

Com isso quero não ter que abrir uma conexão com o banco para cada nova alteração no banco, que é muito frequente.

Comment: Já estava a editar a resposta quando vi o seu comentário. Nesse caso o melhor talvez seja implementar o ChatManager como *Singleton*.

Comment: Oi @ramaral, eu acho que fiz besteira aqui, alterei algo que não fui eu que escrevi.

Bem, sobre o Singleton, por si só não roda em Background. Se eu tentar gravar no banco de dados direto na thread principal, o app trava ou fica lento. Como eu estou instanciando o ChatManager em um serviço e o serviço é Singleton eu não vi necessidade de ter o ChatManager como singleton.

Como então o Singleton vai me ajudar nesse cenário?

Comment: Nunca trabalhei com o Realm mas se bem me lembro do que li ele tem métodos assíncronos(`executeTransactionAsync()`) para interagir com o banco.

Comment: Tem sim, mas ai entra na situação que estou querendo evitar, para cada transação uma abertura do banco. Na documentação há a recomendação para se manter a conexão aberta para uma situação de muitas gravações. O Realm também tem uma condição bem importante: uma conexão só pode ser usada pelo thread que a criou. Não posso usar método `executeTransactionAsync` para alterar um objeto qualquer (chat no meu caso) que tenha sido criado em outro thread.

Comment: Aconselho que estude melhor a documentação pois julgo que não é verdade que "para cada transação uma abertura do banco".